# Using goto within a PHP Switch block. Bad idea?

Tags: php, switch-statement, goto

In the PHP.net documentation for `goto`, there is a [comment](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php#118139), quoted below, that has a -4 score. It looks like a valid use to me. There are no other comments explaining why it's bad either.

> I found it useful for switch statements:

```
<?php
$action = $_GET['action'];
switch ($action){
    case('a'):
        mylabel: {
            doStuff();
            break;
        }
    case('b'):
        if (true){
            doAnotherStuff();
        } else {
            goto mylabel;
        }
        break;
}
?>
```

Despite the unusual `case` keyword usage and the `if (true)` which makes the next `goto` never trigger, I don't think there is anything particularly wrong in the code above.

I would be really grateful if someone could shed a light why his code is downvoted/considered bad.

Comment: `goto` is *generally* frowned upon nowadays. That being said it is not bad per se, it just is *generally* harder to follow the flow of the program. Your example can be achieved by using a `break;` in `case ('b'):` while switching `a` and `b`. Note: Some language solely depend on branching and gotos. It is far from obsolete.

Comment: `goto` just goes somewhere. It's not bad, it just goes somewhere else in your code. What's bad is the reason why you need to go somewhere else in your code. Your example is smelly as hell. Switching cases happens by definition because `case a` is different than `case b`. If you have the need of doing something in case a also in case b, then you need a different structure/algorithm alltogether.

Answer (score 0):

(*More detailed than my comment, point out if something is missed for you.*)

In the case you posted your `switch` can be re-written as

```
<?php
$action = $_GET['action'];
switch ($action){
    case('b'):
        if (true){
            doAnotherStuff();
            break;
        }       
    case('a'):
        doStuff();
        break;
}
?>
```

Now one could argue that this isn't any cleaner (**read better**), it is without a `goto` however. Back to the actual topic: Regarding the comment with the `-4` in score. This doesn't really look like a the case for a `switch` to me. Which is my guess as to why it is so ill-received.

`mylabel` only has a call to `doStuff()` here, why not just invoke it directly instead? Not having to use either a `switch` nor a `goto`.

Now I understand that this is only an example, however try to by-pass it. *generally* it is bad design when you *need* `goto` to make it more clear and/or more ease to manage.

Comment: Do not do that either. A hack versus another hack is as inappropriate. This may generate hours of debug in the future when another programmer - or even yourself - has forgotten about it. You need to count these hours in the equation.

Answer (score 0):

In the scope of that example and not wanting to overchange it beyond its original context, this:

```
<?php
$action = $_GET['action'];
switch ($action){
    case('a'):
        mylabel: {
            doStuff();
            break;
        }
    case('b'):
        if (true){
            doAnotherStuff();
        } else {
            goto mylabel;
        }
        break;
}
?>
```

should be replaced by

```
<?php
$action = $_GET['action'];
switch ($action){
    case('a'):
        doStuff();
        break;
    case('b'):
        if (true){
            doAnotherStuff();
        } else {
            doStuff();
        }
        break;
}
?>
```

The purpose of functions is to avoid you from duplicating code, and that's all you really need here. Also, 2 different cases and no `default` case looks to me that you should be using an `if then else` structure instead.